# Creating different matrices from data frame with R for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, dataframe

I've got 2 data frames (df 1 and 2) that have the following structure:

```
CHR SNP A1 A2 FAM CA1 CA2
1 rs3818361 A G 0.35 7 13
2 rs7561528 A G 0.2 4 16
2 rs6733839 T C 0.45 9 11
2 rs744373 G A 0.45 9 11
2 rs35349669 T C 0.35 7 13
...
```

They have 7 columns and 41 number of rows (without counting the colnames row). With the columns CA1 and CA2 of each one of the data frames I have to build 2x2 matrices, like this:

```
[CA1 from df1] [CA2 from df1] #first row CA1 and CA2 from df1
[CA1 from df2] [CA2 from df2] #first row CA1 and CA2 from df2

[CA1 from df1] [CA2 from df1] #second row CA1 and CA2 from df1
[CA1 from df2] [CA2 from df2] #second row CA1 and CA2 from df2

[CA1 from df1] [CA2 from df1] #third row CA1 and CA2 from df1
[CA1 from df2] [CA2 from df2] #third row CA1 and CA2 from df2
```

I thought about a for loop for (i in 1:41), but i'm having trouble to consolidate the idea.

```
for (i in 1:41) {
do
datai <- c(df1[i,7],df1[i,8],df2[i,7],df2[i,8])
matrixi <- matrix(datai, nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
}
```

I want the loop to generate 41 matrices. The "i" that i put at matrix and data (datai and matrixi) mean "i want 41 of these". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
Map(rbind, split(df1[c('CA1', 'CA2')], 1:nrow(df1)), 
                 split(df2[c('CA1', 'CA2')], 1:nrow(df2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var <- c("CA1", "CA2")
lapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(x) rbind(df1[x,var], df2[x,var]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your answers worked, I also asked someone at my lab for help and it worked, with an alternative. Here i leave you the answer, in case it helps someone:

First, cbind all the columns of all the 7 dfs that i would need into one single data frame: called ¨counts¨. In counts, the structure is like this:

```
counts<-cbind(df1$CA1,df1$CA2,df2$CA1,df2$CA2,df3$CA1,df3$CA2,df4$CA1,df4$CA2
,df5$CA1,df5$CA2,df6$CA1,df5$CA2,df6$CA1,df6$CA2)
```

So, i wanted to

```
res <- list()

for (i in c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
  for (k in c(3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
    for (j in 1:41) {
      tmp <- chisq.test(matrix(c(counts[j,i],counts[j,(i+1)],counts[j,k],counts[j,(k+1)]),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
      res<-c(res,as.list(c(tmp$p.value))) }}}
```

(I wanted the matrices to do a chisq test... that´s why it´s inside of chisq.test(), but there you can see the answer in the middle of the code).

Comment: Regarding my original question, this part is which did the trick: matrix(c(counts[j,7],counts[j,(8)],counts[j,7],counts[j,(8)]),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)